# Conditional Higher Moments for the Trace of the Wishart Process

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations

I need the second, third, and fourth conditional moment for the trace of the Wishart Process, i.e. $V:= X_{11}+X_{22}$, where the dynamics is given by following $\mathcal{S}^+_2$-valued (non-negative cone of symmetric positive semi-definite $2 \times 2$ matrices) Wishart process:
\begin{align*}
d X_t &= \left(\beta Q^\top Q + MX_t+X_tM^\top\right)d t + \sqrt{X_t}\,d B_t^\mathbb{Q} Q+ Q^\top d B_t^{\mathbb{Q}\top}\sqrt{X_t},\quad X_0=x\in\mathcal{S}_2^+,
\end{align*}
where $M,Q\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$, $\mathbb{R}_+\ni\beta> 1$, and $B^\mathbb{Q}$ is a matrix of standard Brownian motions in $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ under some non-unique measure $\mathbb{Q}$. 
Now the dynamics of $V$ is given by 
\begin{align}
d V_t = \left(2\text{tr}\left(MX_t\right)+\beta\text{tr}\left(Q^\top Q\right)\right)d t+2\sqrt{\text{tr}\left(Q^\top Q X_t\right)}d G_t^\mathbb{Q},\quad V_0=v\in\mathbb{R}_+,
\end{align}
where $G^\mathbb{Q}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-Brownian motion taking values in $\mathbb{R}$. Applying Ito's lemma to the dynamics of $V^2$, $V^3$, and $V^4$, taking expectations and using Fubini's theorem, we obtain:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d\mathbb{E}\left(V_t^2\right)}{d t} & = 2\mathbb{E}\left[V_t\left(2\text{tr}\left(MX_t\right)+\beta\text{tr}\left(Q^\top Q\right)\right)\right]+4\mathbb{E}\left[\text{tr}\left(Q^\top Q X_t\right)\right],\\
\frac{d\mathbb{E}\left(V_t^3\right)}{d t} & = 3\mathbb{E}\left[V_t^2\left(2\text{tr}\left(MX_t\right)+\beta\text{tr}\left(Q^\top Q\right)\right)\right]+12\mathbb{E}\left[V_t\text{tr}\left(Q^\top Q X_t\right)\right],\\
\frac{d\mathbb{E}\left(V_t^4\right)}{d t} & = 4\mathbb{E}\left[V_t^3\left(2\text{tr}\left(MX_t\right)+\beta\text{tr}\left(Q^\top Q\right)\right)\right]+24\mathbb{E}\left[V_t^2\text{tr}\left(Q^\top Q X_t\right)\right].
\end{align*}
The solution for $\mathbb{E}\left(\left.V_T\right|V_t\right)$ is given by
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left(\left.V_T\right|V_t\right)& = \text{tr}\left(X_t\,\textbf{exp}\left(2\left(T-t\right)M\right)\right)+\beta\text{tr}\left(Q^\top Q\left(2M\right)^{-1}\left(\textbf{exp}\left(2\left(T-t\right)M\right)-I_2\right)\right),
\end{align}
where $\bf{exp}$ denotes the matrix exponential.
Is it possible to solve these equations in closed-form?